# If period of $\sin^{2m} \sqrt{k}x$, $m\in \mathbb N$ is $\pi$ then find $\lim \limits_{n\to \infty }k^{n}$.

Tags: limits, indeterminate-forms

> If period of $\sin^{2m} \sqrt{k}x$, $m\in \mathbb{N}$ is $\pi$ then find $\lim \limits_{n\to \infty }k^{n}$.

**My attempt:**

Period of $$\sin^{2m} \sqrt{k}x=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{k}}$$

According to question

$$\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{k}}=\pi$$

$$k=1$$

Therefore
$$\lim \limits_{n\to \infty }k^{n}= \lim \limits_{n\to \infty }1^{n}$$

Which is $1^{\infty}$ form.

I think it's answer should be ''Indeterminate" but Wolfram Alpha is saying that answer is $1$.

Can anyone please explain what's the correct answer?

Comment: Does $\sin^{2m}\sqrt kx$ mean $\sin(\sqrt kx)^{2m}$ or $\underbrace{\sin(\sin(\sin(\cdots(\sin}_{2m\text{ times}}(\sqrt kx))\cdots)))$? (Hmm, actually that doesn't matter in this particular case).

Comment: $\lim_{n \to \infty} 1^n$ is not an indeterminate form. It is simply one. Indeterminate forms of the kind $1^{\infty}$ arise if the base is a function of $n$ that tends to $1$ when $n$ tends to infinity.

Comment: It's $$ \sin^{2m}\sqrt{k} x= (\sin \sqrt{k}x)^{2m}$$ @HenningMakholm

Comment: @bharb: The function whose value is $1$ for every $n$ is a perfectly good function that tends to $1$ when $n$ tends to infinity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Indeterminate" is not a number, and it is never an answer to "what is this limit?" The limit either exists (and then it is a real number, or possibly $\pm\infty$), or it doesn't.

What "indeterminate" means here is **neither more nor less** than if you have a limit of the form
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} f(n)^{g(n)} $$
and it turns out that $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(n) = 1$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty} g(n)=\infty$, then *knowing the limits of $f$ and $g$ is not enough to tell you what the value of the original limit is.* It does not mean that the *original* limit doesn't exist (which it may or may not), and it *certainly* doesn't mean that the original limit is "indeterminate". All it means is that you need to find it by some *diffferent* method than taking limits of $f$ and $g$ separately.

In the case of $\lim_{n\to\infty} 1^n$ it is true that the expression asks for a limit *of indeterminate form*, meaning that computing $\lim_{n\to\infty}1$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty} n$ are not going to get you anywhere. So you need something else, but the "something else" easy enough: Each term in the sequence equals $1$, and therefore $1$ is also the limit.